# jQuery changes to DOM inside an interval function don't stick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm trying to build an ad system where every second it checks for new available ads and displays them only if the previous ad has finished displaying. (each ad has an attribute named 'time' which specifies the amount of seconds it should be displayed)

I implemented the program using 'setInterval()', and whenever there's an open slot I would load a template for the ad using '.load()', change texts and images to the ad's texts and images using '.html()' and '.attr("src",...)'.

When running the file, the ad (only one for now) is displayed for a second (it should be four seconds), then the DOM is restored to the original texts and images from the 'template.html'. This operation is executed infinitely, whereas every four seconds the ad would be displayed once for a glimpse of a moment and then the DOM is restored.

I read a lot of posts here about similar problems but none supplied a solution for this specific problem.

Here's the playlist where the ad object is stored:

```
{name: "msg1",
 texts: {txt1: "First ad!",
         txt2: "Come and buy our product!",
         txt3: "It's top secret...",
         txt4: "So it has to be good ;)"},
 images: {img1: "./topSecret.png",
          img2: "http://in5d.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/zdhstrrst.jpg"}}
```

Here's the DOM changes within an interval using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var iterator = 0;
    var count = 1;
    setInterval(function(){
        count--;
        var infiniteLoopPreventor = playlist.length;
        while(infiniteLoopPreventor >0 && count == 0){ //make sure no infinite loop and no previous msg is being displayed
            var now = new Date();
            var currentMsg = playlist[iterator];
            for(var timeSet in currentMsg.timeSets){
                if(currentMsg.timeSets[timeSet].startDate.getTime()<=now.getTime() &&
                    currentMsg.timeSets[timeSet].endDate.getTime()>=now.getTime() &&
                currentMsg.timeSets[timeSet].days[now.getDay()] == 1 &&
                currentMsg.timeSets[timeSet].startTime<=now.getHours() &&
                currentMsg.timeSets[timeSet].endTime>=now.getHours()){
                    //display message
                $( "#result" ).load( currentMsg.template );
                for(var txt in currentMsg.texts){
                    $( "div#"+txt ).html(currentMsg.texts[txt]);
                }
                for(var img in currentMsg.images){
                    $( "img#"+img ).attr("src", currentMsg.images[img]);
                }
                count = currentMsg.time;
                break; //from the for loop which iterates over time sets.
            }   
        }
        iterator = ( iterator + 1 ) % playlist.length;
        infiniteLoopPreventor--;
    }
}, 1000);
});
```

Scrolling through posts asking about similar problems, some suggestions where made as to why it is happening but no proper solutions were offered. The proposed causes were:
 - The changes don't stick because the html was loaded from another page.
 - Asynchronous functions.
 - Problem with the interval, might be solved by using clearInterval() which is not suitable for my problem for I do no wish to stop the interval at any given time.

I would very much appreciate your insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution!

The problem was for some reason with .html() and .attr().

I changed the code so that they would be executed as part of the .load() callback function and it worked.

I would still appreciate an explanation of why the older version didn't work. In the meantime, here's the new piece of code:

```
$( "#result" ).load( currentMsg.template, function(){
    for(var txt in currentMsg.texts){
        $("div#"+txt ).html(currentMsg.texts[txt]);
    }
    for(var img in currentMsg.images){
        $( "img#"+img ).attr("src", currentMsg.images[img]);
    }
} );
```